# jquery append is adding additional extra row up

Tags: jquery

i want to add a new row to a table, the row ia added but each time the row is added it add an extra row on top of the row added, can't seem to get the cause of the problem please can someone help me please
here is  my code

```
$('.addbtn').on('click',function(e){
    var chkedItem = $('input:checked');
    // get the checked <td>
        var chkItemcol = chkedItem.parent().siblings('td');
    // get the checked row numbers of columns
        var chklen = chkItemcol.length;
    //get the texts in the table columns
        chkedItem.each(function(e){
                $this = $(this);
                var qtyclicked = 1;
                var createrow ="<tr><td><input type='hidden' name='qtyclick' class='qtyclick' value='"+qtyclicked+"'/>"+qtyclicked+"</td>";
                // iterate through the columns. 
                for(var i = 0; i<chklen; i++){
                    // add class to the item name
                        if(i == 0){
                                createrow += "<td class='name'>";
                        }else{
                                createrow += "<td>";
                        }
                        createrow += $this.parent().siblings('td').eq(i).text();
                        createrow += "</td>";
                    //alert(createrow);
                }
                createrow += "</tr>";

                    $('.ordertable > tbody:last').append(createrow);


        });
 e.preventDefault();
});
```

and my html code

```
<?php
 $sqlString = "select name,description,type,ingredents,costPerDish from dish where dishcategory='$subcat'";
            $rs = customQuery($sqlString);
            echo "<THEAD>";
            echo "<TR><TH style='background-color:#3366CC'><input type='checkbox' name=''/></TH><TH style='background-color:#3366CC'>Dish Name</TH><TH style='background-color:#3366CC'>Dish Description</TH><TH style='background-color:#3366CC'>Dish Type</TH><TH style='background-color:#3366CC'>Dish Ingredients</TH><TH style='background-color:#3366CC'>Dish Price</TH></TR>";
            echo "</THEAD>";
            echo "<TBODY>";
                while($data= db_fetch_array($rs)){
                        $chkValue = $data[name]."_".$data[type]."_".$data[costPerDish];
                            echo "<TR><TD><input type='checkbox' name='".$chked."[]' class='chked' value='".$chkValue."'/></TD><TD><input type='hidden' class='name' name='name[]' value='".$data['name']."'/>".$data['name']."</TD><TD><input type='hidden' class='description' name='description[]' value='".$data['description']."'/>".$data['description']."</TD><TD><input type='hidden' class='type' name='type[]' value='".$data['type']."'/>".$data['type']."</TD><TD><input type='hidden' class='ingredients' name='ingredients[]' value='".$data['ingredients']."'/>".$data['ingredients']."</TD><TD><input type='hidden' class='costPerDish' name='costPerDish[]' value='".$data['costPerDish']."'/>".$data['costPerDish']."</TD></TR>";
                }
                echo "</TBODY>";
?>
```

the table the the new row is added to

```
<TABLE class="ordertable" style="width:100%; border-collapse:collapse; border: solid 1px #000000">
        <TBODY>

</TBODY></TABLE>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Do you have more than one checkbox that is checked at the time?
Your jQuery code will create one new table row per checked checkbox.